# How should I test "after_create" callback for sending email with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My question is about how to spec a callback for sending an email with the right way.

I have a model called `Question`. After a `question` is created, I have a callback `after_create` to send an email.

I would like to create a rpsec to test this method. However, I already have specs for each Mailer, that verifies if the email is actually sent and the recipients.

So, I would like to know if inside the `after_create` should I test the call of the `send_mail` method or check if the last email sent is present? Because, like I said, the test for email itself is in the spec for the mailer `spec/mailers/question_mailer_spec.rb`

Model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

after_create :send_email

def send_email
   QuestionMailer.send_email(:questioned, self.id)
end
```

Rspec:

```
describe "#send_email" do
  it "should sends email after create" do
     expect(QuestionMailer).to receive(:send_email).with(:questioned, **question.id**) 
     question = create(:question)

  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec this will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **only** test the call to `send_email`.

You want to assert the behaviour of your implementation, and not the implementation itself. In this case, the message sent from `Question` to its collaborator `QuestionMailer`. Remember, test the interface, and not the implementation details.

`Question` does not have a clue how an email is sent. It delegate to `QuestionMailer`. So it makes no sense to check for the last email sent, email queue, and whatnot.

I suggest you to take the time to watch the great presentation Sandi Metz gave on RailsConf 2013: [The Magic Tricks of Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M). The slides are [here](https://speakerdeck.com/skmetz/magic-tricks-of-testing-railsconf).

Best!

*UPDATE: how to handle the `self.id`?*

I think it would be better if you pass `self` rather than `self.id`. Besides solving your problem, it:

- makes your code more expressive;
- avoids using primitive values (integer);
- will probably prevent at least one more database read in your production code.

In case you really want/need to stick with `self.id`, you could `stub` any value in the `Question` instance being tested. Keep in mind that you're **unit testing** `#send_mail`, so it really doesn't matter if the value of `id` is stubbed or generated by the database. And the less you hit the database, faster your tests will run.